# Warning: getimagesize() error profile picture

Tags: images, contact-image

Happy new years all!

I'm having problems showing images uploaded to a profile.

While editing a profile I can upload an image, but upon loading the profile page I get the following error across the top of the page (directory redacted here)

```
Warning: getimagesize(…photo=Mateusz_Pozar_da0ef7da9ecd68e909817e2c733e0d79.jpg):failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in …wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View.php on line 164
```

The line in the php file is:

```
list($imageWidth, $imageHeight) = getimagesize(CRM_Utils_String::unstupifyUrl($image_URL));
```

Trying to open the image directly via "show image" on the profile page I get a 404

```
The requested URL /civicrm was not found on this server.
```

The specified directory for uploaded images is plugins/files/civicrm/custom/ and I can see the four images I've tried uploading and they look fine when opened directly.

Could this be caused by a too big or heavy image?

I'm running WP 4.4 and CiviCRM 4.6.6

Cheers / M

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there's a settings mismatch.  Check the values of "Image Directory" on **Administer menu > System Settings > Directories** and "Image Upload URL" on **Administer menu > System Settings > Resource URLs**.

If the two look correct, please update the original question with the values so we can see them.